# How to save web page as PDF?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

There is a webview in the app and a "Save" button on top of the webview.

After clicking the "Save" button currenturl will be saved to a TableView on another ViewController. Everything works fine.

Now I would like to also save the web page as PDF to the same TableView and can open it after clicking. How can I do that?

The following is codes for saving currenturl. savedURLs is the array to save all urls on another ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class BrowserViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var browser: UIWebView!

    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let currentURL = browser.request?.URL?.absoluteString  {
            savedURLs.append(currentURL)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currentURL, forKey: "currenturl")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedURLs, forKey: "savedURLs")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSavingVC", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is the obj-c answer, I think you can convert the code to swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066212/ios-save-web-page-as-pdf

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna try and let you know if it is ok.

Comment: Hi Eugene, please put it as an answer so I can confirm it. Thanks.

Comment: done, check it out. Thank you.

Comment: hey, Mike, just curious why my answer got unaccepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Swift code for converting webPage to image, then you can convert it to PDF:

```
    let sizevid = CGSizeMake(1024, 1100)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizevid);

    webview.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    var imageData = NSData()

    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage)!

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let pathFolder = String(String(format:"%@", "new.png"))

    let defaultDBPathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathFolder)

    let defaultDBPath = "\(defaultDBPathURL)"

    imageData.writeToFile(defaultDBPath, atomically: true)

    // After converting it in to an image you can easily convert it as pdf.
```

Comment: Great Answer! After saving as Image I can find it on Photo Library but after saving as pdf I can not find it anywhere on the device. How to find the converted pdf document on iPhone? iBooks or something?