# NSData to PDF, save the file(pdf), open the file(pdf)?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I have `NSData`. How can I convert the `NSData` to a PDF file in Swift? How can I save this PDF file? How can I open the PDF file after it has been saved?

This is what I have so far. The `NSData` object is called "data.File".

```
let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.File.bytes), data.File.length)
let cgDataProvider =  CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(cfData)
let cgPDFDocument  =  CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(cgDataProvider)
```

Comment: what kind of data that is? is it an image data?

Comment: here is the similar question I answered, maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36633813/how-to-save-web-page-as-pdf/36776749#36776749

Comment: CFData is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, NSData.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/).  What problem are you trying to solve: converting `NSData` to PDF, saving data to a file, or opening a data from the file?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?